# Showing % sign in displayformat

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to add a trailing % sign to a decimal field in a grid. I currently have displayformat set to '##.00%' Is there any way to do this without the framework multiplying my value by 100 and having it flip flopping between showing decimal (0.55 when the cell is selected) and percent (55% when the cell is not selected).

I wouldn't care so much if it was consistent, but now I am having an issue when I am inserting a row into said table, and now when I set the cell value 0.55 (after a row inserted event) it reads 0.55% in the UI.... even when I select the row and lost focus after said insert.

Thanks
-Kyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page FA202010 does a similar formatting: `##0.0000%`. 
Here is the ASPX for the label/field combo:

```
<px:PXLabel ID="lblTotalPercents" runat="server" EnableClientScript="False" 
style="z-index:100;position:absolute;left:769px; top:9px; width: 74px;">Total Percent:</px:PXLabel>

<px:PXNumberEdit ID="edTotalPercents" runat="server" DataField="TotalPercents" Decimals="4" LabelID="lblTotalPercents" 
      MaxLength="8" DisplayFormat="##0.0000%" style="z-index:101;position:absolute;left:851px; top:9px; width: 98px;" TabIndex="10" ValueType="Decimal">
</px:PXNumberEdit>
```

With editor control in edit mode:
[image]

Same value in display mode:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the example, might also be something wrapped up into the fieldselecting event.

Comment: FA202010 uses DepreciationCalculation graph which doesn't declare FieldSelecting events. It seems functionality is achieved with DisplayFormat but I believe it's possible to play around with FieldState/FieldSelecting to achieve something that looks similar with a string field instead of a decimal field.